# how to push 1D Vector to Mat?

Tags: opencv, vector, svm, mat

I am calculating HOG featureVector of size 1764 from 531 images of size 32x32.
how can I push this vector to a row in a Mat training image.

feature Vector:
1 dimensional, size 1764
total vectors= 531(for all training images)

Training Image:
Mat image of type 32FC1, rows= 531, col = 1764

Comment: Mat push_back might be a good starting point..

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31338186/5008845)