# Insert data in two channel matrix

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV and its developing. I have two channel matrix

```
Mat alleigen( Size(3,3) , CV_32FC2)
```

I have data:

```
A=[1,2,3]

B=[4,5,6]

c=[7,8,9]
```

I want to insert as like M matrix

```
M= [1 4 7
    2 5 8
    3 6 9]
```

How do I do that in OpenCV?

Comment: Why is your matrix 2 channel? `M` seems a single channel matrix to me. Which data of `A`, `B` or `C` should go on the first or second channel? Are you sure you want a **2 dimensional** matrix, instead of 2 channel?

Comment: CV_32FC2 means two 32-bit float channels

Comment: @Miki how to do it in single channel matrix any idea ?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824787/opencv-multi-channel-element-access

Comment: @Miki i want to do it by using loops for coloum one loop and rows one loop i dont want to insert data manually. i need two loops to insert those values. any idea ?

Comment: You don't need loop to insert values in rows. Check my answer and let me know

Comment: @AlexStepanov that answer was fine 6 years ago for multichannel matrices, now the api evolved a lot :D. Also here seems that he doesn't need multichannel matrices at all.

Comment: @Miki Ah, I wish everybody could hear your words and finally stop writing plain C code and compile it with a C++ compiler

Comment: @waruniguna please edit your code into the question, because right now it's unclear where A,B,C comes from, and which values you want to put in M.

Comment: @Miki could  you please provide me a good article to read.

Comment: as soon as I understand what you want to do, I'll look for something specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't want a 2 channel matrix, but a simple 2 dimensional matrix:

This following code will produce the desired output:

```
A:
[1, 2, 3]

B:
[4, 5, 6]

C:
[7, 8, 9]

M:
[1, 2, 3;
 4, 5, 6;
 7, 8, 9]
```

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat1f A = (Mat1f(1, 3) << 1, 2, 3);
    Mat1f B = (Mat1f(1, 3) << 4, 5, 6);
    Mat1f C = (Mat1f(1, 3) << 7, 8, 9);

    Mat1f M(3,3);

    A.copyTo(M.rowRange(0, 1));
    B.copyTo(M.rowRange(1, 2));
    C.copyTo(M.rowRange(2, 3));

    cout << "A: " << endl << A << endl << endl;
    cout << "B: " << endl << B << endl << endl;
    cout << "C: " << endl << C << endl << endl;
    cout << "M: " << endl << M << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i want to use loop like 
for(int i=0;i<coloumn.size;i+) {
for (int j=0; j< row.size; j++){
M.insert[i][j]
}} like method any idea ?

Comment: How do you declare the matrices A,B and C?

Comment: Do you just want to declare M with subsequent values? Or do you want fill it with values from matrices A, B, and C?

Comment: A is in code Mat destination(3, 3, CV_8UC1); which has values.

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far? edit it into the question, please

Comment: thank you very much. if you can please drop me a suitable tutorial to read. thank you so much.

Comment: I just drop a some links to get you started: [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31894250/5008845), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31338186/5008845). Also note that OpenCV documentation comes with [nice tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html), and you can find most answers to your need with Google or StackOverflow